# Porting from xbox to windows 8

Tags: windows-8, xbox

We have application developed for XBOX 360 which is silverlight based app. We need to port it on windows 8 platform ... tabs and desktop.

Here are some questions

- will the porting possible?
- Is it good idea to port against rebuild from scratch on winRT instead of SilverLight?
- Does XBOX has metro style applications same as on windows phone 8 platform?

Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Thanks
Rashmi

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but there will be work involved.  It won't just run.  Most of your business code will work fine, but your UI will require updating to the new Windows8 XAML namespaces and concepts.
2. I would suggest porting your business logic, but re-implementing your UI.  You can likely re-use many assets, but the interaction paradigm between a controller (or Kinect) and a touch/mouse interface will be quite different.  Just porting will likely end up with an app that doesn't feel right on Windows 8.
3. There is no WinRT/Metro style UI on the XBox.

Answer (score 0):

porting over would be possible.
however you might have to re-code certain part of the code-behind because the api for winrt is slightly different.

i believe the guide for porting is similar to the one for porting windows phone to windows 8.

you should port since most of the xaml code should not have much changes.

Comment: If I have the xbox code , do i need xbox to run it? I mean I just want to see what the app is all about so is there any xbox emulator/simulator kind of concept?

Comment: if i wasn't wrong, there is no official xbox emulator from microsoft